# Setting variable from image select array, send to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the code below for users to select a thumbnail from a PHP array of images in a form.  I am trying to figure out a way so that when the user submits the form this is on, which ever image is displayed currently will be passed through the form to the PHP Post.  I'm not sure how to do this.  Logically think of it as, if image[1] is active, I want to send that url to the form.  Currently, the PHP var $knoteImgs[] are full  tags, if I need to put the img tag in the JS it may be cleaner to obtain the URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image = new Array(3)
image[1]="<? echo $knoteImgs[0]; ?>"
image[2]="<? echo $knoteImgs[1]; ?>"
image[3]="<? echo $knoteImgs[2]; ?>"
var num = 1;

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(galleryNext){
num=num+1
if (num==4)
{num=1}
document.getElementById('knoteImg').src=image[num];
});

document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', function(galleryPrevious){
num=num-1
if (num==0)
{num=3}
document.getElementById('knoteImg').src=image[num];
});
</script>
```

Edit: if anyone could even link me to some relevant posts that would be useful. In not sure what to search for.

**Edited my original post to show working code:**
Thanks to @GaryHayes and @Brad for the assistance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image = <?php echo json_encode($knoteImgs); ?>;

var tot = image.length;
var c = 0; // current image (array key index)

function loadImage(){
  $("<img/>").attr({src:image[c], id:"knoteImg", class:"img-thumbnail"}).load(function() {
      $('#thumbnail').html( this );
  }); 
}
loadImage(); // load 1 image

$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
  id= this.id==='next' ? c++ : c-- ;
  c= c==-1 ? tot-1 : c%tot ;
  loadImage(); 

});
function getimage() {
document.getElementById('currentimage').value = document.getElementById('knoteImg').src;
var thumbnail = document.getElementById('currentimage');
alert(thumbnail.value);
}
</script>
```

`alert(thumbnail.value);` is triggered by:

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentimage" name="currentimage" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="getimage();" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: You realize that the argument to the callback function in addEventListener is the event, not a gallery ?

Comment: Careful... you're not escaping data for use in JavaScript properly.  Try `var image = <?php json_encode($knoteImgs); ?>;` instead.

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure I follow 100%. I have a link to toggle forward and backward through the images.

Comment: Place a hidden input field in your form and apply image info to it on submit button press, just before processing. It works nicely, I do it all the time.

Comment: @GaryHayes this is what I'm trying to do.  I can work out the hidden input, but I'm not sure how to pass the info from JS as to which image is currently displayed?

Comment: @Brad, I'm not sure I understand the use of json_encode here.  Do I place them in place of each of the images in the array or just once?  I can't seem to get the syntax working correctly.

Comment: Without any JS mumbo-jumbo one could simply use radio buttons, and place the images into the `label` elements of those radio buttons … and then maybe hide the radio buttons via CSS, and apply a style based on the radio button selection to highlight the chosen image …

Comment: @KevinO'Brien `json_encode()` will serialize the entire array at once.  Use the syntax in my previous comment, but I seem to have left out an `echo` in front of `json_encode`.  `var image = <?php echo json_encode($knoteImgs); ?>;`  This will become `var image = ["image1", "image2", /* etc */];`

Comment: @Brad cool thanks for clarifying with the `echo`.  Will this help me in the future when I have arrays that may not be larger than 1 image?  So I don't have to manually create the array in JS?  I'll probably need to edit the If statement in JS to be a little more versatile?

Comment: @KevinO'Brien If you serialize an empty array, it will output `[]` as expected.  If you have an array with a single image, it will output `["singleimage"]`.

Comment: @Brad, well right now I'm trimming the array down to 3 items in PHP, but there may be cases where there are not more than one, or even sometimes 0.  I just haven't created those statements yet in PHP. 

Using json_encode in JS this way, do I need to use `var array = image.split(",");` to separate the string?

Comment: @KevinO'Brien Try it and see.  You're not sending a string to JavaScript, you're sending an array literal.  Like I said, if you use `json_encode()`, you don't need to do **anything else**.  Whether you have an empty array, array with one element, array with a million elements, it doesn't matter.  That array will be inserted directly into your JavaScript as an array literal which the JavaScript engine will handle for you.  Try it and see.  Look at the output of your PHP in your JavaScript and you will understand.

Comment: @Brad thanks for the help.  I've got it working, I changed the code for displaying / toggling through the images based on some of your comments.  Edited my question to show working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML in form:

```
  <input type="hidden" id="currentimage" name="currentimage" />

    <input type="submit" onclick="getimage();" value="Submit" />
```

Your Function in Javascript:

```
function getimage() {
document.getElementById('currentimage').value = document.getElementById('knoteImg').src;
}
```

SOmething like this... sorry if not perfect... not testing live.

Comment: This is working for me, I will likely use this as answer.  Just a note, I tried to bind the onclick="getimage();" to my "Previous" and "Next" buttons on the image gallery, so that when you click them it will just update the variable, but that is not a good solution, because it returns the current value, rather than the one that will load when clicked.  Thanks for the solution :)